# Why is a Windows 10 routing table entry apparently being ignored?

Tags: windows-10, networking, routing

I’m trying to use the Windows 10 `route add` command to direct some traffic to a local network instead of through a gateway. It works on some computers but not on others.

Here’s the background. I manage a small business network with a modem/router at 192.168.**2**.1 serving as the Internet gateway. It would be very disruptive to change that address. Also, the router’s subnet mask is limited to changes on the fourth octet 255.255.255.**X**; there is no way to change the third octet.

There are five Ethernet-connected Windows 10 computers on the network with fixed IP addresses. There are also two Ethernet-connected weigh scales which can be assigned only fixed IP addresses of the form 192.168.**0**.x. The network is configured so the computers can communicate with the scales through simple network hubs without going through the router. Here’s part of the network.

[image: simple diagram showing modem/router, computer, and scale all attached to hub]

Until some time in July 2020, it was sufficient to set the subnet mask on the computers to `255.255.252.0`, and then a computer at 192.168.2.x could communicate with a scale at 192.168.0.x. However, that has stopped working. Communication with the scales is the only problem that arose in July -- the computers can still communicate with each other and with the Internet without any difficulty.

There was a Windows 10 upgrade at approximately the time of the first scale communication failure, and perhaps the upgrade somehow precipitated the problem. However, I have access to another network, upgraded at the same time, where the problem does not appear. Also, I haven’t seen any reports on the web of an issue like this associated with that round of upgrades.

Instead of setting the subnet mask to `255.255.252.0`, I’ve tried to use `255.255.255.0` as the mask and explicitly set the route for the scales to be addressed directly, rather than through the gateway:

`Route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0`

This does not work. In particular, when a scale cannot be addressed, the rejection message is coming from the ISP – the gateway is involved, as shown in more detail below.

As an alternative to communicating with the scale, I’ve created a test which I can also run on a different network where there is no scale. Neither network has any devices at 192.168.6.x. Here’s the command which I used:

`Route add 192.168.6.0 mask 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0`

Having created that route, I then issued the following command to see if the added route was working:

`tracert -h 5 -w 25 192.168.6.80`

On one network, the one without the scale, tracert returns what I’d expect – it’s the Windows 10 computer where I issue the command which cannot find the device:

```
  1     *     Howard-W7.home [192.168.1.11]  reports: Destination host unreachable.
```

However, on the network where I originally encountered the problem (the network with the scale), the message is directed to the gateway and tracert tells me that eventually it’s a router at my ISP which cannot find the device:

```
  1   100 ms     1 ms     1 ms  mynetwork [192.168.2.1] 
  2    13 ms     7 ms    26 ms  10.11.1.17 
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     8 ms     7 ms     7 ms  tcore4-toronto12_37.net.bell.ca [64.230.59.200] 
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

On both computers, the structure of the routing table (from ROUTE PRINT) is the same, though for obvious reasons the IP addresses are different.

This ROUTE PRINT output is from the problem computer. The newly-added route does appear in the table. All specified destinations are shown with the Gateway as On-link, which should mean that the Gateway at 192.168.2.1 is not used. I see that the first route in the table is also listed as persistent, twice; I’ve been assuming that’s not my problem.

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1     192.168.2.13     35
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.2.13    291
     192.168.2.13  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.2.13    291
    192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.2.13    291
      192.168.6.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.2.13     36
    192.168.6.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.2.13    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.2.13    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.2.13    291
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1  Default 
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1  Default 
===========================================================================
```

This ROUTE PRINT output is from the computer without the problem. As far as I can see, the structure of the table is identical. Nonetheless, this computer does not try to route messages to 192.168.6.0 via the external gateway.

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.11     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.11    281
     192.168.1.11  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.11    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.11    281
      192.168.6.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.11     26
    192.168.6.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.11    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.11    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.11    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Because the two routing tables are so similar, I suspect that whatever diagnostic information I need does not appear in these tables.

Can anyone explain why the requested routing is not working reliably? Can anyone suggest other network settings to inspect or other diagnostics to run? Alternatively, can anyone offer a good workaround without an adequate explanation?

Comment: An IP address that is in a different network cannot be “on-link.” You can tell Windows to send the traffic out a different interface but you can’t tell Windows to try to send traffic directly to an IP address that doesn’t exist on its local subnet without using a gateway. The problem here is that you can’t communicate with the scales. Did you also change the subnet mask on the scale? The difference is it takes two to tango. Your computer might send direct to the scale but the scale will reply to the default gateway. Meaning it’s the routers that are causing the different behavior.

Comment: You can confirm this much easier by using a packet capture tool like wireshark. Then it all becomes clear where the packets are going and coming from.

Comment: What exactly is "not working". What happens if you ping the devices? Can the PCs ping each other, can they ping the scale, can they ping the router, can they ping an external IP or domain name (e.g. superuser.com)?

Comment: The output of the `tracert` command, which IP did you try to trace exactly? Which subnets did the devices have at that time, which manual routes did you set up?

Comment: @Appleoddity: A single Ethernet network can perfectly well have several IP networks "on-link", on the same link. (This is now standard in IPv6 and widely used by home routers, but also seen with IPv4.)

Comment: @user1686 An interface can have multiple subsets attached and with that multiple IPs. But the computer will never consider an IP address outside of its subnet as “on link.” It’s simply not how IP routing works.

Comment: @Appleoddity: No, it's exactly how IP routing works. If the matching route has a gateway address set, then the network is off-link and the packet is sent to the gateway's MAC address; if the route doesn't have a gateway, then the network is on-link and the packet is sent to its own destination's MAC. Whether it's Windows or Linux, the "local subnet" has no special significance other than automatically defining such a route without a gateway, and nothing prevents you from adding more such routes like OP did.

Comment: I'm the OP responding to some comments. I'm currently using Wireshark to gather more information (as suggested by Appleoddity), and it will take me a while before I will have any results to report. In the meantime, I've edited my posting: I noted that, after I defined a route for 192.168.6.x, I was trying to tracert 192.168.6.80 (which does not exist on the LAN), and I clarified that the only communications problems are with the scales at 192.168.0.x; all of the computers with IP addresses 192.168.2.x can communicate with each other and with the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the command `route add` wrong. It's used to route specific subnets through specific routers (using specific network interfaces). There are a lot of sites explaining this, e.g. [this site](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/).

What you are actually doing by using `Route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0` is to route the traffic for subnet `192.168.0.0/24` through the gateway `0.0.0.0`. Which "does not make sense" (and doesn't work).

This being said, your previous network setup workaround (using different subnets for the same LAN) should still "work", the way to go here is to determine the source of the problem first (see my comment).

**Alternatively**, instead of using your old network setup workaround, I would suggest to put PCs and router on subnet A e.g. `192.168.2.0/24` the two scales on subnet B e.g. `192.168.0.0/24` and

A) use a router to route between the subnets or

B) add a second IP address to your PCs from your scale's subnet (you can add multiple IPs to a NIC in Windows 10)

Note: B will only allow for a connection between scales and PCs not between router and scales